# How to properly multiply and divide numbers in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with multipliying numbers.
I have number type fields with ui-money-mask directive from https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks  where I can type numbers with 2 decimal. 
But I want to store those numbers without separator, I mean:

123.12 -> 12312

1111.11 -> 111111 etc.

The problem is that when I'm trying to multiple them by 100 to remove separator sometimes I'm getting wrong result, like:
1111.11 * 100 = 111110.99999999999 but I want 111111.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Multiply, and then do a simple Math.floor(number)?

Comment: Note that this is **not** wrong result. It's just floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for tips.
So I have to use toFixed() or Math.round.
Can I be sure that it always round the number correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical floating point arithmetic issue. In your case I think that the simpliest solution is simply to round:

```
Math.round(1111.11 * 100)
```

It works in the same way as `toFixed(0)` except it does not return a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [`toFixed(0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Try like this

```
parseFloat("111110.99999999999").toFixed(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply

```
Math.round(1111.11 * 100)
```

Comment: Because it does not work. `parseInt(1111.11 * 100) == 111110`

Comment: yeah, Thanks. Corrected

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using toFixed or Math.round

```
var result = parseInt(parseFloat(1111.11).toFixed(0));
```

NB: toFixed returns string need to convert it again to integer

**OR**

```
var result = Math.round(1111.11 * 100)
```